# Retrieve FQDN for multiple Servers in CMD prompt

Tags: cmd, echo, ping, fqdn

I have been given a list of server names and asked to retrieve their fully qualified domain name.

```
SERVER1
SERVER2
SERVER3
```

in the company we have multiple potential FQDN so I have been given a basic cmd file to run

```
@ECHO OFF
PING %1.EXAMPLE.COM
PING %1.EXAMPLE2.COM
```

You can see the purpose is to ping all potentials till I get a return and that will be the FQDN.

However there are 600 for me to ping. I am wondering if it is possible to read the list of servers from a text file all at once and return the results of the pings to another text file. Thanks

Comment: `for /f %A in (c:\myfile.txt) do echo %A` See `for /?` as there are heaps of options. If in a batch use `%%A` instead of `%A` when typing.

Comment: See also `ping /?` for options.